# Ant script to Find a jar file given the class name?

Tags: java, ant

how to  find the name of jar which contains  the specific class through ant script?

Comment: is the name of the class the same as the name of the .jar file?

Comment: Nope..it's different...all the jars are in a directory whose location  is known . i tried with  shell  script but it's taking a lot f time to search. :(

Comment: A long time to search? I gave you a shell script based answer below, and I'd love to see a solution that solves your problem any faster.

Answer (score 3):

We are using the following Ant code to find the jar containing our main class. It requires Ant 1.8+.

```
<whichresource class="${main.class}" property="main.class.url">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${jar.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </classpath>
</whichresource>

<pathconvert property="jar.file">
    <url url="${main.class.url}" />
    <regexpmapper from="jar:file:/(.*)!.*" to="\1" />
</pathconvert>

<echo>Jar file containing main class: ${jar.file}</echo>
```

I hope this answers your question.

Maarten

Answer (score 1):

Try [jarscan](https://jarscan.dev.java.net/) . It is a commandline java tool, it should be easy if you want to integrate it through ant also.

Comment: this doesnt  seem working for me, since i cant use third party jar finder softwares?? there must be some JAVA API for the same ?? or ant command ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem can be better solved by a 1-line (ok, 5-line) C-shell script. Suppose you are trying to find a list of jar files in some directory that contain a certain file. Try this at your csh prompt:

```
% cd directory_where_your_jar_files_reside
% set f2Search = filename_you_are_looking_for
% foreach jarFile (*.jar)    
? (jar tvf $jarFile | grep $f2Search > /dev/null) || echo $jarFile
? end
```

You can obviously concat the output to some other file if required. This is a Unix solution, dunno how to do this on Windows, sorry. Apologies for not answering the Ant question, but others have answered it already. Hope this helps, - M.S.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really what Ant is for.

Ant is primarily a build tool, and it's core functionalities revolve around that. Yes, it can be used for additional functions, but it's still best to use it what it was intended for. Finding a class inside a JAR file isn't what it's good at.

You may be better off just doing this in Java. Java offers functionality to open up JAR files and inspect the contents. You can use those to find the class you are looking for. Or, use another tool that's intended to do that, such as the Jarscan that Biju mentions.

Comment: You don't know what this information is used for. In my case, we use it for generation of the JNLP of the webstart application. So yes: we need to know which jar contains a certain class and yes: we do need that information for building our application.

Comment: In this case, I would assume you know where the class is *before* you put it in a JAR. That would be a very different case than receiving a large quantity of JARs and trying to find out where a particular class is being loaded from. In other words, your case seems quite different than that of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, one approach that might work is to loop through all the JAR files and pass each one to the `available` task as the lone `classpath` path element. The class you're interested in would be used for the `classname` attribute.

Edit: Since it sounds like you're now entertaining non-Ant solutions, here's a variation of the find-my-class code:

```
import java.net.URL;

public class ClassFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
        URL url = c.getResource(c.getSimpleName() + ".class");
        System.out.println("location of " + args[0] + ": " + url);
    }
}
```

With Java 6, you can use classpath wildcards (see ["Understanding class path wildcards"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)), so it should be easy to include your directory of JARs and see how fast it is.

Edit2: And if you want to find multiple locations...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.JarURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class ClassFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String classResourceName = args[0].replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class";
        ClassLoader loader = ClassFinder.class.getClassLoader();
        Enumeration<URL> classResources = (loader == null) ? ClassLoader.getSystemResources(classResourceName) : loader.getResources(classResourceName);
        if (classResources.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("Locations of " + args[0] + ":");
            while (classResources.hasMoreElements()) {
                URL url = classResources.nextElement();
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                String loc = (conn instanceof JarURLConnection) ? ((JarURLConnection)conn).getJarFile().getName() : url.toString();
                System.out.println(loc);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No locations found for " + args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **rfeak** this is not what ANT is designed for. Having said that, it can very be a frustrating to determine how to resolve missing class dependencies.....

I use the [findjar](http://www.findjar.com/index.x) website. It indexes most of the available open source libraries.